# C++ Внешний метод не видит класс и поле класса

Tags: c++, ооп, функции, классы, дружественная-функция

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Human; 


class Apple
{
private:
    int weight;
    string color;

public:
    Apple(int weight, string color)
    {
        this->weight = weight;
        this->color = color;
    }

    friend void Human::TakeApple(Apple& apple);
};


class Human {
public:

    void TakeApple(Apple& apple);

};

void Human::TakeApple(Apple& apple)
{
    cout << "Human takes apple " << "Weight = " << apple.weight << endl;
};

int main()
{
    Apple greenApple(100, "Green");

    Human human;

    human.TakeApple(greenApple);

    return 0;
}
```

Получаю две ошибки:

1. использование неопределенного типа "Human" Не смотря на то, что вначале указал прототип класса Human
2. идентификатор "weight" не определен  , хотя метод указан как дружественный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто ставьте все своим чередом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Apple;

class Human {
public:

    void TakeApple(Apple& apple);

};


class Apple
{
private:
    int weight;
    string color;

public:
    Apple(int weight, string color)
    {
        this->weight = weight;
        this->color = color;
    }

    friend void Human::TakeApple(Apple& apple);
};



void Human::TakeApple(Apple& apple)
{
    cout << "Human takes apple " << "Weight = " << apple.weight << endl;
};

int main()
{
    Apple greenApple(100, "Green");

    Human human;

    human.TakeApple(greenApple);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это уже особенность плюсов, что нужно всё определённом порядке писать?
А если у меня будет два класса, имеющие методы, которые берут значения из другого класса, внешними функциями вообще не получится пользоваться?

Comment: вписывать тело методов в определение класса - это плохая привычка. Сначала типы, классы с предварительным объявлением методов , а уже потом сами методы. @Vadim Didenko

Comment: @AlexGlebe Наоборот, вписывать тело методов в определение - хорошая привычка, и выносить их реализацию отдельно стоит только в случае необходимости.

Comment: Важно, чтобы в объявлениях использовались только указатели или ссылки на неполные объявления. Тогда работайте, сколько хотите.